# Cannot search based on multiple id in find query in Cakephp 3

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I have two tables category and product. I want to get details of product whose id are passed in conditions array of find query. The problem is when i pass condition as an array, it returns

> Cannot convert value to integer

Secondly, if i debug it by passing only one id it returns category record, but it should return product record. Please help to solve my issue.

My code is as follows:

```
 public function display()
    {
      $ids = array(1,2,3,4,5);
      $c_List = $this->Products->Categories->find('all',array('conditions'=>array('Categories.category_id'=>$ids)));
      $data = $c_List->toArray();
       debug($data);
       die();
    }
```

> Model - ProductsTable.php

```
public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        parent::initialize($config);

        $this->setTable('products');
        $this->setDisplayField('product_id');
        $this->setPrimaryKey('product_id');

        $this->belongsTo('Products', [
            'foreignKey' => 'product_id',
            'joinType' => 'INNER'
        ]);
        $this->belongsTo('Categories', [
            'foreignKey' => 'category_id',
            'joinType' => 'INNER'
        ]);
    }
```

> Model - CategoriesTable.php

```
public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        parent::initialize($config);

        $this->setTable('categories');
        $this->setDisplayField('category_id');
        $this->setPrimaryKey('category_id');

        $this->belongsTo('Categories', [
            'foreignKey' => 'category_id',
            'joinType' => 'INNER'
        ]);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

When you are finding the records based on an array of ids, use **IN** in the condition clause.

```
public function display()
    {
      $ids = array(1,2,3,4,5);
      $c_List = $this->Products->Categories->find('all',array('conditions'=>array('Categories.category_id IN'=>$ids)));
      $data = $c_List->hydrate(false)->toArray();
       pr($data);
       die();
    }
```

Comment: This will only solve part of the problem. OP should be performing the find on `Products`, not on `Categories`. This should work: `$this->Products->find('all',['conditions'=>['Categories.category_id IN'=>$ids]])`

Comment: @InigoFlores You have to think about the other cases too. Like he may have the category_id column in the categories table(for category tree view), means a category(child category) can belong to a parent category.

Comment: In this particular case, OP wants `Products`. *"I want to get details of product whose id are passed in conditions array of find query. "*